# How to map document Reference to POJO in firestore firebase for kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

[image]
In this content is Reference to Biomarkers/PR

```
data class CancerBiomarker (
    val type : String?= null,
    val biomarkers : List<Biomarkers> = emptyList()
)

data class Biomarkers(
    val title: String? = null,
    val content: Biomarker? = null
)

data class Biomarker (
    val content:String? = null
)
```

This is my data class. In that content is declared as Reference.After running this I am getting following exception and if I change  content to DocumentReference then also I am getting exception

```
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not deserialize object. Can't convert object of type com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference to type com.firestorepoc.model.Biomarker
```

How to map reference to POJO model?

```
 val firebaseFirestore: FirebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
        firebaseFirestore.collection("CancerBiomarker")
            .get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot> { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    val result : MutableList<CancerBiomarker>? = task.result?.toObjects(CancerBiomarker::class.java)

                } else {
                    Log.w("Document", "Document " + "Error getting documents.", task.exception)
                }
            })
```

Comment: Please edit the question to show the exact data of the document you're trying to map.  If the types don't match, you will get that error.  The message suggests that you've stored a string in the content field rather than a reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the following error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not deserialize object. Can't convert object of type com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference to type com.firestorepoc.model.Biomarker

Because you have declared the `content` property in your `Biomarkers` class to be of type `Biomarker`, while in the database is actually a `DocumentReference`. So the exception is raised because there is no way in Kotlin in which you can cast an object of type `DocumentReferenc` to an object of type `Biomarker`.

To solve this, you have to change the `content` property to be of type `DocumentReference` as it is in your database.

Besides that, I see that the `biomarkers` property is an array. If you need to map that array to a list of `Biomarkers` objects (`List<Biomarkers>`), please check out the following article:

- [How to map an array of objects from Cloud Firestore to a List of objects?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-map-an-array-of-objects-from-cloud-firestore-to-a-list-of-objects-122e579eae10)

Comment: Event if I change val content: Biomarker? = null to val content: DocumentReference? = null it is throwing exception as Failed to convert value of type java.lang.String to DocumentReference

Comment: It sounds like you have then some objects in the database that hold a String value rather than a DocumentReference, right?

Comment: On reference path, I have string value

Comment: The type of the object in your class should match the type in the database. If you have in the database a `DocumentReference` then in your class the property should be of type `DocumentReference`. If it's a String, declare it as a String.